# ToLookup, LINQ and Index

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections

I have the following situation (VB.NET, .NET 4):

Generic list of custom objects  `letters(Of Letter)`

`A, B, C, B, D`

need a collection containing items and its indexes:

```
A (0)
B (1, 3)
C (2)
D (4)
```

Some tries:

```
Dim letters As New List(Of Letter)
Dim query As ??? = letters.Select(Function(letter, index) _
                            New With {index, letter})

Dim lookup As Lookup(Of Letter, Integer)
lookup = letters (query).ToLookup(???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use the overload of [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) that supports an index to create a tuple(or `KeyValuePair`) of letter and index. Then use the overload of [`ToLookUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211.aspx) that takes selectors for both key and value.

You might need to either supply an `IEqualityComparer<Letter>` to `ToLookUp`, or override *both* `Letter.Equals` and `Letter.GetHashCode()`. Those two need to be overridden together so they are consistent, or you'll get wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim lookup = Enumerable.Range(0, letters.Count).ToLookup(Function(i) letters(i))
```